# How to make a layout, with cardviews compatible for every android screen size device?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-cardview

I am trying to make this layout compatible for every android screen size. I have tried many things like making different layout folders but its not working.
I have also follow this link, but I don't understand it much.
[Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_mehandi"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:onClick="photo"
                    android:id="@+id/photographerImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/vender_photographer" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Photographer"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the issue just need to add weight instead of margins from different size.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_banner_background"
            android:text="Vendors Type"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/buttonText"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/firstPanel">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_mehandi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:onClick="photo"
                        android:id="@+id/photographerImageView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@drawable/vender_photographer" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Photographer"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_barat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:onClick="cat"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@drawable/vender_wedding_caterer"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Caterer"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/secondPanel">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_walima"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="2
                "
                android:layout_margin="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:onClick="org"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@drawable/vender_wedding_organizer"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Organizer"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_nikah"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:onClick="flow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@drawable/vender_flower_deco" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Flower Decorer"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/thirdPanel"
            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_engagement"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:onClick="dec"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@drawable/vender_wedding_decorations" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Wedding Decorator"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_aqeeqah"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:onClick="dj"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@drawable/vender_dj"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="DJ"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>







        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
```

**Compile this dependency into your gradle file and use sdp instead of dp like**

```
android:width="@dimen/_40sdp"
```

**and it will work for all devices.**